# Performance Considerations When Setting the Cookie Expiration Date

Tags: 7, cookies

Are there any performance considerations to take into account when setting a Drupal cookie to expire 10 or 20 years in the future?

I know it's not possible to set a cookie to never expire as per the cookie specification, but I saw people showing ways to set a cookie expiration date of 2038 on this Stack Overflow thread:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3290424/set-a-cookie-to-never-expire/3290474

I  know Drupal has a `sessions` table in the database. I went through ours and saw that the records were not too long.

I'd expect the sessions table to get longer once we set garbage collection far into the future.

I guess one consideration to take into account for Drupal would be the database resources like memory and hard drive capacity and also average number of users every month.

The only other drawback would be MySQL would have to look up the session record for each hit. With an extremely long table we might start seeing performance degradation. We currently have about 1000 records with the default Drupal cookie and garbage collection settings.

I guess one approach we could take would be to set the cookie to expire far into the future and then see fast how the sessions table fills up.

I guess what I'm asking is are there any other performance considerations that I have not mentioned that I need to be aware of?

Also, would Drupal create a new session record in the DB for each hit by a spambot? I know they are constantly searching the web for places to spam and that Google Analytics may not be reliable for counting the number of hits in this situation. These can add up pretty fast.

This question is for Drupal 7 but any advice on Drupal 8 is also welcome.

Comment: Given that the session id is part (D7) or all (D8) of the primary key for the sessions table, you might think about approaching the research from that point of view. For example there's some interesting information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332300/is-there-a-real-performance-difference-between-int-and-varchar-primary-keys) about how varchar primary keys perform on large tables. I'd recommend reading all the answers, at least one of them mentions the performance of larger varchars which is where you're at (256 combined for D7, 128 for D8)

Comment: Thanks Clive! I guess this is an analysis of algorithms question.

Comment: More than performance considerations there should be security issues to consider in having cookies valid for 20 years, which would mean users are practically always logged in (if they don't manually delete the cookies). What would happen if somebody steal the laptop I have not used in the past 3 months? If the cookie would last 20 years, the thief would be able to access the site with my account.

Comment: Thanks @kiamlaluno for your response. I do understand the risks you mentioned but in my case the data protected is not that sensitive, but I will mention this to stakeholders.

Comment: If also the session cookies expire after 20 years, the sensitive data at risk are the account passwords and emails. That is the least set of sensitive data users have.